# After Updating Android Studio to 2.3, it gives me error message "No JVM installation found"

Tags: android, android-studio

After I updated Android Studio I now get this error message when I try to open it.

[image]

Any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: Are you running  `studio64.exe` ?

Comment: It seems you are trying to run an 32 bit of Android Studio but you don't have an 32 bit version of JVM So i will not run until you install an 32 bit JVM. You are running an 64 bit windows so most probably you should run `studio64.exe`!

Comment: Got it  Bros   thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run an 32 bit of *Android Studio* but you don't have an 32 bit version of JVM So it will not run until you install an 32 bit JVM.

**Also** You are running an 64 bit of *Windows* so most probably you should run `studio64.exe`